# how to add a other node with data in Mongo db existing cluster?

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 node cluster (Mongodb1,mongodb2,mongodb3) in which one of them(Mongo1) i have changed the data path(/`mongodb-disk`/data) .I have attached old data drive into that db node. i want to make connection with cluster to sync that db with other nodes. Now this node is become other node . and i am unable to change rs.conf file where "*id" : "rs*`clarifi"`, "host" : "ip-172-31-25-55.ec2.internal:27017", "host" : "ip-172-31-21-48.ec2.internal:27017",`enter code here` "host" : "ip-172-31-20-181.ec2.internal:27017", i did $ mongo rs_clarifi:OTHER>cfg = rs.conf() rs_clarifi:OTHER>cfg.members[0].host = "mongodb1:27017" rs_clarifi:OTHER> rs.reconfig(cfg) { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "replSetReconfig should only be run on PRIMARY, but my state is REMOVED; use the \"force\" argument to override", "code" : 10107, "codeName" : "NotMaster" }

Answer (score 1):

```
    I execute these command to all 3 node 
    use local
    db.system.replset.find()
     db.system.replset.remove({ "_id" : "rs_clarifi", "version" : 10, "members" : [ { "_id" : 1, "host" : "ip-172-31-25-55.ec2.internal:27017" }, { "_id" : 2, "host" : "ip-172-31-21-48.ec2.internal:27017", "arbiterOnly" : true }, { "_id" : 3, "host" : "ip-172-31-20-181.ec2.internal:27017", "priority" : 2 } ] })
    My didnt loose my data and  then
rs.initiate( {
   _id : "rs0",
   members: [ { _id : 0, host : "mongodb1:27017" } ]
})

by this i again make an replication,.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add new node only on master (configuration will be replicated on all cluster nodes). 
Cluster nodes will connect to new node and instruct new node (update its configuration).
Old data can be removed from disk, node will synced automatocally.

Comment: But i need old data and i want to sync with it the new existing cluster.

Comment: @DevvratTomar Then you need initiate new replica set on desire node (with old data) and add other data nodes in this cluster.

Comment: @DevvratTomar Besides you can create dump from old node and upload it on your cluster (mongodump/mongorestore utilites helpt you).

Comment: i am getting mongodb3:27017
        syncedTo: Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
        1494837918 secs (415232.76 hrs) behind the primary